# how can I filter the files for download in the blueimp jquery download program

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, blueimp

I'm trying to use the Blueimp jQuery File Upload File program https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload. I've searched through wiki & documentation but couldn't find an answer to how to filter the files available for download.

I am using it inside an authenticated 'protected' area. I have successfully prepended all my uploaded files with a unique id ( e.g. UID-filename.jpg ), which I will have available in the authenticated session. So all I have to do is select only the ones with the correct UID.

The jquery code that shows the download table is :

```
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
<!--    <tr class="template-download fade">-->
    <tr class="template-download ">
    {% if (file.error) { %}
        <td></td>
        <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
        <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
        <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
    {% } else { %}
        <td class="preview">{% if (file.thumbnail_url) { %}
            <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="gallery" download="{%=file.name%}"><img src="{%=file.thumbnail_url%}"></a>
        {% } %}</td>
        <td class="name">
            <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
        </td>
        <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    {% } %}
    <td class="delete">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}">
            <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
            <span>{%=locale.fileupload.destroy%}</span>
        </button>
        <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1">
    </td>
</tr>
```

I'm not very experienced in JS/Jquery. I would appreciate any ideas on what to do next. is anyone familiar with a setting/option to filter these files. Alternatively, I assume that file is array of filenames or paths which i suspect could be filtered.In PHP I'd probably use the glob function .Does anyone have any experience with this in JS?

Thank you in advance,

Bill

Comment: I have made some progress towards a solution. I asked github https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/1578 . The plugin author suggested that I filter on the server side. I found https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/1149 which explains how to filter on the server side. I've done this and it works as far as uploading. I now have it setup where each user has a subfolder in the upload folder named their unique ID number which contains their images. 1 Problem: Uploaded images not visible. Please see https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/1587

Comment: Links are dead.

Answer (score 1):

use the plugin http://sunnywalker.github.io/jQuery.FilterTable/ 
It works on any table and is easy to deploy.

Include dependencies:

```
<script src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/bindWithDelay.js"></script> <!-- optional -->
<script src="/path/to/jquery.filtertable.js"></script>
<style>
    .filter-table .quick { margin-left: 0.5em; font-size: 0.8em; text-decoration: none; }
    .fitler-table .quick:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
    td.alt { background-color: #ffc; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.2); }
</style> <!-- or put the styling in your stylesheet -->
```

enter the code

```
<script>
$('table').filterTable(); //if this code appears after your tables; otherwise, include it in your document.ready() code.
</script>
```

Okay! Good luck!